# List of all the Indexes in the firebird

Tags: firebird

I am trying to list out the all indexes from the Firebird. I am using DBworkbench tool for Firebird database. With this tool, I can see around 200 indices in my database. I want a query to list of all these indices with its related tables and column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a special tool for this, just write a simple query in your favorite tool.

The system table [RDB$INDICES](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref-appx04-indices.html) stores definitions of both system- and user-defined indexes. The attributes of each column belonging to an index are stored in one row of the table [RDB$INDEX_SEGMENTS](https://ib-aid.com/download/docs/firebird-language-reference-2.5/fblangref-appx04-idxsegments.html).

This query will return information about non-system indexes:

```
select * from RDB$INDICES where RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 0;
```

To get information about name, table name and field name of non-system indexes may use:

```
select 
    rdb$indices.rdb$index_name,
    rdb$indices.rdb$relation_name,
    rdb$index_segments.rdb$field_name
from rdb$index_segments
   right outer join rdb$indices on (rdb$index_segments.rdb$index_name = rdb$indices.rdb$index_name)
where 
   (
      (rdb$indices.rdb$system_flag = 0)
   )
```